# Required Sender ID not supplied in config or env variable - 500 Internal Server Error (Azure Function - Http Trigger)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I have Azure Function (Http Trigger) working in Visual Studio and showing an output in localhost.

[image]

Now, I am trying to test in the Azure Function portal.

But, there is no output.

I am getting "500 Internal Server Error".
[image]

I was able to find this details from Monitor's Invocation Details.
[image]
What am I missing? Where do I add this "Sender ID"?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to not having "Application setting" configured.

I had to go to "Configuration" option on the left menu and add each Name and Value for required configuration.

[image]